Why non-final class instance variables are allowed in lambda expressions but local non-final variables aren't?
The following two code listings are separately accessing a non-final class instance variable and a non-final local variable. The former caused no warning/error, while the latter did. In my opinion they both will cause race conditions.
According to The JLS §15.27.2:

The restriction to effectively final variables prohibits access to dynamically-changing local variables, whose capture would likely introduce concurrency problems.

However, if they do want to lower the risk of concurrency issues, why not also prohibits the accessing of non-final class instance variables?
code listing 1 (no compiler warning/error):
public class Main {
  private int a = 0;

  private void run() throws Exception {
    Runnable task = () -> {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        a++;
      }
    };
    Thread t1 = new Thread(task);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(task);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      new Main().run();
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
  }
}

code listing 2:
public class Main {

  private void run() throws Exception {
    int a = 0;
    Runnable task = () -> {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        a++;  <--- compiler complains here
      }
    };
    Thread t1 = new Thread(task);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(task);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      new Main().run();
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
  }
}

Related question: Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final
Someone in the remarks pointed out that

Class members are covered/affected by the memory model, which if followed, will produce predictable results when shared. Local variables are not, as mentioned in §17.4.1

I do not understand what is so special about the heap memory that class instance variables reside in, and it is not explained clearly in §17.4.1

What's so special about fields? Because their behaviour is very well specified with regards to the memory model (the whole section 17.4 specifies this). How local variables should behave when shared is not specified. Is it possible to specify it? Yes. Has anyone been bothered to do it? No.

The short answer is "closures".  Or more specifically, the JVM architecture does not support closures involving variables on the stack.
When you create a lambda, you are creating something that can be called at any time after the creation ... until the lambda becomes unreachable.  If the lambda refers to a variable, then that variable needs to be available whenever the (future) lambda calls are made.

If the variable is a field of an object, that can be implemented by storing a reference to the object in the lambda.

If the variable is a final (or effectively final) local variable, that can be implemented by storing the value of the variable in the lambda.  (The actual variable's value can't be changed ... so storing it is ... fine.)

If the variable is a non-final local variable, it will cease to exist when the method or constructor that owns it exits.  But the lambda may be retained and called after that.  And if it was called after the method exited, the lambda wouldn't be able to read or write the (now non-existent!) variable.  That is a problem.
So, the JLS doesn't allow it.  Rather, it says that a lambda (or an inner class) is not permitted refer to a non-final local variable or parameter.  Problem solved.



I notice that the JLS text that you quoted says:

... whose capture would likely introduce concurrency problems.

That is also true.  My understanding is that potential concurrency problems were not the primary motivation for this restriction in the inner class case ... which also has this restriction.  But I can see that concurrency would be a significant concern for lambdas accessing or mutating local variables.

In a pure functional language this problem wouldn't arise since nothing (not the lambda, not any other code) would be able to modify the variable.  Another possible solution would to put the "frame" containing a method's local variables on the heap.  Neither of these approaches would work for Java.  (The latter is too complicated and too expensive.)
